# How to set up a JQuery selector for a HtmlInputHidden-field in a server control

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating a server control called DateTimePicker. In this I have a property that get/sets the time format. I've tried to store the time format in a hidden input field.

```
public class DateTimePicker : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private TextBox _dateTextBox;
    private TextBox _timeTextBox;
    private HtmlInputHidden _timeFormat;
    ...
    public string TimeFormat
    {
        get
        {
            string timeFormat = _timeFormat.Value;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeFormat))
            {
                timeFormat = DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT;
            }
            return timeFormat;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeFormat.Value = value;
        }
    }
    ...
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        _dateTextBox = new TextBox();
        _dateTextBox.ID = "DateTextBox";
        _dateTextBox.CssClass = "DatePickerInput";

        _timeTextBox = new TextBox();
        _timeTextBox.ID = "TimeTextBox";
        _timeTextBox.CssClass = "TimePickerInput";
        _timeTextBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(70);

        _timeFormat = new HtmlInputHidden();
        _timeFormat.ID = "TimeFormatInput";

        Controls.Add(_dateTextBox);
        Controls.Add(_timeTextBox);
        Controls.Add(_timeFormat);
    }
    ...
```

The textbox holding the time is extended with a JQuery time picker like this:

```
$('.TimePickerInput').timePicker({
    step: 60,
    timeFormat: GetTimeFormat()
});


function GetTimeFormat() {
    var timeFormat = $('#TimeFormatInput').val();   //This does not work
    return timeFormat;
    //return 'hh:mm:ss tt';                    //This works
};
```

The setter and getter for the server control works, but in the selector for the HtmlInputHidden-field does not work. How can I set up this selector correctly?

Edit (Here is the generated html):

```
<div> 
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCgLwj7S1AQLalbH6BQKys6HCBwLLy8GzCQKVnffiAgKC8LSoDgKTgNnOAQKM54rGBgK5ttWBDwLR0LuADBg3bjYl8jVMd+TqBkYL8mvSQmAH" />
</div>
<div>   
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        //<![CDATA[
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('form1'));
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tUpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90);
        //]]>
    </script>

    <div id="UpdatePanel1">
    <span id="LoadTimer" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
            <span id="FromDateTime"><input name="FromDateTime$DateTextBox" type="text" id="FromDateTime_DateTextBox" class="DatePickerInput" /><input name="FromDateTime$TimeTextBox" type="text" id="FromDateTime_TimeTextBox" class="TimePickerInput" style="width:70px;" /><input name="FromDateTime$TimeFormatInput" type="hidden" id="FromDateTime_TimeFormatInput" /></span>    
            <br />
            <br />
            <span id="ToDateTime"><input name="ToDateTime$DateTextBox" type="text" id="ToDateTime_DateTextBox" class="DatePickerInput" /><input name="ToDateTime$TimeTextBox" type="text" id="ToDateTime_TimeTextBox" class="TimePickerInput" style="width:70px;" /><input name="ToDateTime$TimeFormatInput" type="hidden" id="ToDateTime_TimeFormatInput" /></span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Postback" id="Button1" />
            <br />
            <br />        
            <input type="submit" name="GetDateTimeButton" value="Get Selected DateTime" id="GetDateTimeButton" />
            <input name="SelectedDateTimeTextBox" type="text" id="SelectedDateTimeTextBox" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

After looking at the source, I've tested using 
    var timeFormat = $('#FromDateTime_TimeFormatInput').val();
This works, but the 'FromDateTime_'-part is added from the id used for the server control. I have to get a way to get it without knowing that. If it is more than one 'TimeFormatInput'-fields on the page, it does not matter which one i'll read, the will have the same content.

Comment: Please show us the full generated HTML code.

Comment: I found this selector to work:
    
    var timeFormat = $('[id$="TimeFormatInput"]').val();

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.net seems to mangle the ID, you need to use `$('#FromDateTime_TimeFormatInput')` to select the element.

Please do not use `$('[id$="TimeFormatInput"]')` as it will be extremely slow - it needs to iterate over **all** elements and then perform a substring comparison.

Comment: I updated the typoff in the question. Using '#TimeFormatInput' as selector still does not work.